# Stripes and Jquery and Ajax for dynamic dropdowns

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, json, stripes

I am using Stripes for the web tier. I want to include two dropdowns where the list of items in the second dropdown is dependent on the value chosen in the first.

Pretty straightforward Ajax you say. I can't find a single example of doing this. The examples on Stripes site are all trivial, like updating a label. I read, that the JSON returned by Stripes is funky  & not straightforward for jQuery to handle. How can I do that? An example would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Google Gson (https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)
For example:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public Resolution autocomplete() {

    List<String> opts = new ArrayList<String>();

    ...

    String json = new Gson().toJson(opts);
    return new StreamingResolution("application/json",json);
}
```

Comment: I am posting the complete test program here for other Stripes/Json folks that may have the same questions.  I have a 2 field java bean called Item , which holds a name value pair. This gets serialized and gets sent across to the jsp page. The example is trivial, the first dropdown is a habitat dropdown, the next dynamic dropdown is a list of animals that live in that habitat. the user choices are also bound and saved to the selectedHabitat and selectedAnimal.

Answer (score 0):

The javascript part ( using jQuery) is fairly straightforward. You attach a change handler to the first `<select>` and for each change make a request to server for data specific to the new value.

The response could be JSON or html. Following assumes server will return html:

```
$('#select_1').change(function(){
    var data={ select_1_val : $(this).val() };
     /* make ajax request and load result into select_2*/
    $('#select_2').load('/path/to/server', data);    
});
```

At your server controller you would process a GET request and extract the value of the GET param `select_1_val` and do whatever back end magic is needed to return just a set of `<option>` tags

Answer (score 0):

```
    package com.rajamma.dealmeister.domain;

public class Item
{

int value;
String label;

public int getValue()
{
    return value;
}

public void setValue(int value)
{
    this.value = value;
}

public String getLabel()
{
    return label;
}

public void setLabel(String label)
{
    this.label = label;
}

public Item(int key, String name)
{
    value = key;
    label = name;
}
 }
```

The Action Bean

```
  package com.rajamma.dealmeister.web.actions;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import net.sourceforge.stripes.action.DefaultHandler;
import net.sourceforge.stripes.action.ForwardResolution;
import net.sourceforge.stripes.action.Resolution;
import net.sourceforge.stripes.action.SessionScope;
import net.sourceforge.stripes.action.StreamingResolution;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.rajamma.dealmeister.domain.Item;

    @SessionScope
    public class DropDownActionBean extends AbstractActionBean
    {

        List<Item> habitatList = new ArrayList<Item>();
        List<Item> animalList = new ArrayList<Item>();

        private String selectHabitat = "1";
        private String selectAnimal;

        public DropDownActionBean()
        {

            habitatList.add(new Item(1, "Land"));
            habitatList.add(new Item(2, "Sea"));
            habitatList.add(new Item(3, "Air"));

            animalList.add(new Item(1, "please choose Habitat"));

        }

        public List<Item> getHabitatList()
        {
        return habitatList;
        }

            public void setHabitatList(List<Item> habitatList)
        {
            this.habitatList = habitatList;
        }

        public List<Item> getAnimalList()
        {
            return animalList;
        }

        public void setAnimalList(List<Item> animalList)
        {
            this.animalList = animalList;
        }

    public String getSelectHabitat()
    {
        return selectHabitat;
    }

    public void setSelectHabitat(String selectHabitat)
    {
        this.selectHabitat = selectHabitat;
    }

    public String getSelectAnimal()
{
    return selectAnimal;
}

public void setSelectAnimal(String selectAnimal)
{
    this.selectAnimal = selectAnimal;
}

@DefaultHandler
public Resolution test()
{
    return new ForwardResolution("/WEB-INF/jsp/deal/DropDownTest.jsp");
}

public Resolution populateDropDownList()
{
    if (selectHabitat.equals("1")) // Land
    {
        animalList = new ArrayList<Item>();
        animalList.add(new Item(1, "Lion"));
        animalList.add(new Item(2, "Tiger"));
        animalList.add(new Item(3, "Horse"));
        animalList.add(new Item(4, "Elephant"));
    }
    if (selectHabitat.equals("1")) // Land
    {
        animalList = new ArrayList<Item>();
        animalList.add(new Item(1, "Lion"));
        animalList.add(new Item(2, "Tiger"));
        animalList.add(new Item(3, "Horse"));
        animalList.add(new Item(4, "Elephant"));
    }
    if (selectHabitat.equals("2")) // Sea
    {
        animalList = new ArrayList<Item>();
        animalList.add(new Item(1, "Whale"));
        animalList.add(new Item(2, "Shark"));
        animalList.add(new Item(3, "Dolphin"));
        animalList.add(new Item(4, "Octopus"));
    }
    if (selectHabitat.equals("3")) // Sea
    {
        animalList = new ArrayList<Item>();
        animalList.add(new Item(1, "Eagle"));
        animalList.add(new Item(2, "Vulture"));
        animalList.add(new Item(3, "Swift"));
        animalList.add(new Item(4, "Crow"));
    }
    String json = new Gson().toJson(animalList);
    return new StreamingResolution("application/json", json);
}

    public Resolution submit()
{
    return new ForwardResolution("/WEB-INF/jsp/deal/DropDownTest.jsp");
}

    }
```

The Stripes/JSP page

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="stripes" uri="http://stripes.sourceforge.net/stripes.tld" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>

<html>
<head><title>Simple jsp page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-latest.js"></script>    
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function invokeForJson(form, event, container) {

                    params = {};
                    if (event != null) params = event + '&' + $(form).serialize();            
                 $.post(form.action,
                    params,
                        function (data) {
                         var listItems = "";

                        if (data) {
                             for(var i = 0; i < data.length;i++)
                             {
                                listItems+="<option value='" + data[i].value + "'>" + data[i].label + "</option>";
                         }
                         $(container).html(listItems);   
                        }
                    });
    }


        $(function() {
                $('#dropdown1').change(function() {
                    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
                invokeForJson($('form')[0], 'populateDropDownList', '#dropdown2');
                });         
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>

<stripes:form beanclass="com.rajamma.dealmeister.web.actions.DropDownActionBean">
    <stripes:select  id="dropdown1" name="selectHabitat">
          <c:forEach var="item" items="${actionBean.habitatList}">
                <option value="${item.value}">${item.label}</option>
        </c:forEach>
    </stripes:select>

    <stripes:select name="selectAnimal" id="dropdown2">
              <c:forEach var="item" items="${actionBean.animalList}">
                <option value="${item.value}">${item.label}</option>
        </c:forEach>
    </stripes:select>

    <stripes:submit name="submit"/>


</stripes:form>

</body>
</html>
```